# Dynamic React Select with Axios

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, axios, react-select

I'm just starting out with adding some React to my Ruby on Rails front end.

I have two data model called `coffee_beans` and `countries`.

I want to add a select dropdown on a form for `coffee_beans` that pulls in the country, both `id` and `country_name` fields. I need to submit the id to the `coffee_beans` table.

I am able to retrieve the data via axios just fine, but I'm struggling to get the data to show in my dropdown.

I am using React-Select.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';

class Country extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`/countries.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const countries = res.data;
        this.setState({ countries });
      })
  }

  render() {
    let optionItems = countries.map(countries => 
        <option key={countries.id}>{countries.country_name}</option>
    );

    return (
        <div className="">
        <label htmlFor="coffee_beans_countries">Country</label>
            <Select id="country" name="coffee_beans[countries]" options={optionItems} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Country
```

**rendered element**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Country from 'Country'

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("country-component");
    ReactDOM.render(<Country />, element);
});
```

**Update**
 I now have the below code, but am getting the error:

> warning.js:33 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or
>   forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';

class Country extends React.Component {
    state = {
        countries: []
      }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`/countries.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const countries = [];
        this.setState({ countries });
      });
      console.log(countries)
  }

  render() {
    let optionItems = this.state.countries.map(countries => 
        <option key={countries.id}>{countries.country_name}</option>
    );

    return (
        <div className="">
        <label htmlFor="coffee_beans_countries">Country</label>
            <Select id="country" name="coffee_beans[countries]" options={optionItems} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Country
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get countries not defined on line 20: let optionItems = countries.map(countries =>

Comment: In future it's a good idea to put details like that in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

`let optionItems = countries.map`

should be

`let optionItems = this.state.countries`

and you also need to set an initial state. So:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';

class Country extends React.Component {
  state = {
    countries: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const countries = []
    this.setState({ countries });
  }

  render() {
    let optionItems = this.state.countries.map(countries =>
      <option key={countries.id}>{countries.country_name}</option>
    );

    return (
      <div className="">
        <label htmlFor="coffee_beans_countries">Country</label>
        <Select id="country" name="coffee_beans[countries]" options={optionItems} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<Country />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-joltvp).

Comment: I now get - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'countries' of null

Comment: You need to set state as well.

Comment: No, you don't have an initial state. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Colin. I'm not getting another error. I've just updated the OP.

Comment: Would need to see more of your code to answer that one, and you should open a new question :)

Comment: So you're not using another component to render `Country`?

Comment: I am and have just added the code, but pretty sure this part isn't the issue. Might be wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since countries is the only thing in state, try 
    `this.state.map(countries => ...`
          -OR-
In componentDidMount,
    `this.setState({countries: countries})`

Answer (score 0):

For the Updated Warning: I had the same problem a couple days ago, but I was using the fetch api, so I don't know if it's going to work. I just made my componentDidMount() async and put a await before every async method I called inside it. 
This is the final result:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this._getUserData();
}

_getUserData = async () => {
    try {

        const response = await fetch(url);
        this.setState({firstAccess: responseJson.data.name});

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I'm new to React and JavaScript so I'm not sure why it works, but it seems like React is just trying to warn you that the setState() inside the Promise can be called when the Component is not mounted already, this situation will happen if you call another setState bellow your axios call, causing the component to re-render (don't know if that's considered unmounted as the warning said) and there is a change the promise setState will be called right there. If you make componentDidMount async, it allows you to wait for the Promise to be solved and you won't have the problem. But again... I'm not sure haha.